# bar mitzvah medals

Tags: gifts, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

Long ago, I received a bronze bar mitzvah medal that I have always treasured.  I am looking to purchase one now but I can't seem to find any of this minted year.  The few I have seen online all seem to be very old.  Does anyone know where I can purchase a recently minted one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.worldofjudaica.com/jewish-art/israel-coins-and-medals-corp/p_bronze_medallion_with_bar_mitzvah_theme_and_twelve_tribes_design?utm_source=gshp&utm_medium=dcpc&utm_campaign=israel_coins_and_medals_corp&gclid=Cj0KCQjw_o7NBRDgARIsAKvAgt0iTH-CvbPoyQziVca131DXZOY0B9_jo03MJVfYSLRZ5iExPyj173kaAhtNEALw_wcB#!#p=59071) you go for bronze.

[Here](http://www.worldofjudaica.com/jewish-art/israel-coins-and-medals-corp/p_sterling_silver_medallion_with_twelve_tribes_logo_and_bar_mitzvah_theme?utm_source=gshp&utm_medium=dcpc&utm_campaign=israel_coins_and_medals_corp&gclid=Cj0KCQjw_o7NBRDgARIsAKvAgt196efft5II-kKcfCIn9ZCA7VGJBV50x4FIGk4ByUQPyv9_vz1tzfwaAkFEEALw_wcB#!#p=59079) you go for silver.

These are not from the current year (I'm not sure if they exist) but they do not have the year on them (only on the box) so it should do fine to give as a gift to a bar mitzvah boy.

Comment: It seems that they are not minted every year?

Comment: @itsmikem - Yup.